# If qty is 2 at first line item and 3 at second line item, the values of bbb info displaying should equals to qty

Tags: xml

If qty is 2 at first line item and 3 at second line item, the values of bbb info displaying should be equals to qty.
If qty is 2 at first line item and 3 at second line item, the values of bbb info displaying should be equals to qty.

```
    If qty is 2 at first line item and 3 at second line item, the values of bbb info displaying should be equals to qty.
```

Expected output should be:
qty 2 bbb 1111 2222
qty 3 bbb 3333 4444 5555

```
 '''
              <?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252" standalone="no"?>
<xyz>  
 <ddd>
                <abc> 
                  <!-- First line item -->
                    <aaa qty = "2" />
                </abc>
                <abc>
                   <!-- Second line item -->
                    <aaa qty = "3" />
                </abc>
        </ddd>
                
                 <bbb serial = "1111"/> 
                 <bbb serial = "2222"/> 
                 <bbb serial = "3333"/> 
                 <bbb serial = "4444"/> 
                 <bbb serial = "5555"/>
</xyz>
      
  '''      









'''   
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        
        <xsl:template match = "xyz/ddd" >
            <xsl:for-each select="abc">
                <!--<xsl:value-of select="aaa/@qty"/>-->
                <xsl:variable name="loop">
                    <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::xyz/bbb"> 
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat(@serial,',')"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:value-of select="$loop"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:template>
        
    </xsl:stylesheet>  
  '''
     




  If qty is 2 at first line item and 3 at second line item, the values of bbb info displaying should equals to qty.
    qty 2 bbb 1111 2222
    qty 3 bbb 3333 4444 5555
```

Comment: Data is not usually send in the fashion above.  Usually you will have aaa with quantity followed by bbbs then another aaa followed by bbbs.  You have aaa, aaa, then bbbs which  very rarely happens with data.

Comment: Yes,You are right. But this is how customer needs!!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what technology you want to use, but in XSLT 3.0 you could do

```
<xsl:iterate select="//aaa/@qty">
  <xsl:param name="start" select="1"/>
  <qty count="{.}">
    <xsl:copy-of select="subsequence(//bbb, $start, xs:integer(.))"/>
    <xsl:next-iteration>
      <xsl:with-param name="start" select="xs:integer(.)"/>
    </xsl:next-iteration>
  </qty>
</xsl:iterate>
```

Comment: Thank you!!  And Sorry, we were using XSLFO version=1.0